# c++ bus error:10 while trying to parse and update string

Tags: c++, bus-error

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int main() {

  char* start = "There are no";
  char* d = start;
  char* s = d;

  while (s) {
    char c = *s++;
    if (ispunct(c) || isspace(c)) {
      continue;
    }
    *d++ = c;
  }

  printf("%s\n", start);

}
```

I am new to c/c++ and trying to understand to manipulate strings. The above code scans through the string and skips punctuations and spaces and prints the string without any punctuations and spaces.

While I run it I get "Bus error: 10"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If this is c++ please use std::string and iostream instead

Answer (score 1):

`start` is [`string literal`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal), it's implicitly `const`, modify it will invoke **undefined behavior**. try:

```
char start[] = "There are no";
```

or just use string:

```
std::string start("There are no");
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative solution, but I am still curious to know why the above code didn't work.

Comment: it's `string literal`, impilcitly `const`

Answer (score 1):

You are checking for a wrong thing in the loop condition. You should check for `*s`. `s` is a *pointer* and it will hardly ever become `0` in your code. Ultimately, you step into an unmapped memory region which causes `SIGBUS`.

Comment: That said, it's not a bad idea to check your pointer isn't NULL (0) before dereferencing it either.

Comment: You still get the same error as being said you cannot modify string literal

Comment: The other response nailed it down. Your string is effectively a read-only string. Change to an explicit array declaration and the string will become mutable.